# I want to learn English for 3 months

Tags: british-english

I'm Egyptian and I want to learn English for 3 months. What advice do you have for me?
I'm free for 3 months.
What is the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Find someone who speaks English well and **listen**. Talk in English whenever you get a chance. Read in English--out loud. Write in English, whenever you get a chance. Arrange for someone who reads and writes English well to evaluate your writing. see http://www.studygs.net/langlearn.htm

Comment: In engineering school I was in class with a guy from Egypt who claimed to have learned English by reading American comic books.  (Not that I recommend this.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a list of resources.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - The OP doesn't ask for a list of resources. He is merely soliciting general advice.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, go and live with a family in a primarily English-speaking country that includes young children, and whose members speak only English (perhaps as a paying guest or lodger). It will probably seem hard at first, because you will be throwing yourself in at the deep end (though you have clearly made a good start with your acquisition of English, judging from how well you have constructed your question).

The presence of the kids will expose you to some fairly basic aspects of learning the language, and the repetitiveness of many basic sentences will help you to consolidate what you are hearing and speaking.

Get involved with the family's activities, and try to forget about the age gap that exists between you and the kids. Letting go of your inhibitions and any tendencies you may have to be self-conscious or to over-analyse your mistakes will take you a long way, because it will enable you to **have fun** while you are learning. This will greatly improve your ability to commit what you are experiencing to memory, and will also provide you with additional emotional content that will make what you are learning a lot more meaningful to you. You will also learn quite a lot about the culture of the people you are living with, which will provide you with some additional hooks of information on which to hang the English you are learning at the same time.

Similarly, I expect that showing them photos of your own family and telling them something about yourself and your own way of life will break down many barriers of shyness and cultural distance.

I'm sure this doesn't need saying, but if you are polite and give consideration to the family's priorities as well as your own, you will give your relationship with them the best possible opportunity to flourish. You may even end up with lifelong friends.

To begin with, I would suggest you pay much more attention to listening to and speaking English than to reading and writing it (which would in any case be rather a distraction in the context of living in this kind of setting, where something unexpected will always be happening). Listening and speaking will be a valuable early skill for to you acquire, and making a good start here will give you all the necessary confidence to tackle the later stages of reading and writing (perhaps after you return to Egypt).

Essentially, what I am suggesting is that you try to learn English the way any child learns its mother tongue — by a combination of constant repetition, question-asking, immersion and lack of self-consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

If you study eight hours a day, you can work through a one-volume course book of English and assimilate the basic rules of English. But it is rare that one can occupy oneself eight hours a day studying a foreign language. This requires knowledge and experience in the techniques of learning a language. So I would suggest that you take lessons with a private teacher, one lesson a day, and continue studying at home. You should also have material for learning. One or two course-books, a beginners dictionary and/or an electronic dictionary, one or two basic grammars. Graded reading material and bookmark any helpful English websites on your computer.

And the most important thing of all, you should document what you have done, what you have learnt. Just to give you an example. Many years ago I studied Turkish for about three weeks and got a basic understanding of that language. After twenty years, I have an idea of how that language system works but I can't remember more than two or three words because I never did anything in Turkish since that time. But I still have my notes of what I learnt about grammar, pronunciation, vocabulary and texts I worked through. If I were to study those notes again, I could have in one week the knowledge I had acquired in three weeks.

Today such documentation is much easier with a computer, tablet or smartphone. Nevertheless any documentation needs some sort of organisation or system in order for it to succeed. .